# Consistency of view content when including documents

Tags: couchdb

The [CouchDB documentation on views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Altering.2BAC8-Changing_Views) states that when using `include_docs=true` when querying a view, the included documents' revisions may be newer than the ones used to generate the view. This seems very strange to me as I understand that MVCC was designed to exactly solve these race-conditions without blocking writers. The alternative presented there mentions including the document in the view's values.

Is it true that a request with `include_docs=true` may return a newer document (or none, if the document was deleted) than was used to generate the view or does this only happen when also using `stale=ok` to query a view without updating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's true. What happens is that each query will retrieve the document identified by the "id" attribute of the query result row; the documents are not saved into the query index, as with the results emitted for the map function. Note that this potentially makes the query slower, because every involved document has to be looked up, retrieved and included in the response. Emitting the full doc is elides that concern, but will of course make your index file much larger on disk.